# Enabling/Disabling Service Best Practice

Tags: spring, spring-boot

Imagine we have `ServiceA` which should be working in some profiles, but disabled (i.e. calling to that service should not do anything) in others.
I see 2 ways of implementing it:

- Having `isEnabled` property

then implementation could be something like

```
public class ServiceA {
    @Value("${isEnabled:true}")
    private final boolean isEnabled;

    public do() {
      if (!isEnabled) return;
      ...
    }
}
```

cons here is that it kinda breaks single responsibility principle and also if we have a lot of methods, all of them should have `if(!isEnabled)`

- Leverage conditional annotation

Here we'll need interface for `ServiceA` and 2 implementations: `NoOpServiceA` (empty implementation) and `RealServiceA` both having `@ConditionalOnProperty(name = "isEnabled", ...)` on them. This way there will be no `if`'s inside methods and less chances of doing mistake, on the other hand it will create a lot of additional classes and could hinder understandability of the code.

What option would you choose or is there a better approach for this?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this would help you achieve what you want but I did something like this to enable/disable my `RestController`.

```
 @RestController
 @ConditionalOnExpression("${personcontroller.enabled:false}")
 @RequestMapping(value = "temp", produces = "application/json;charset=UTF- 8")
 public class PersonController {
    @RequestMapping(value = "test")
    public ResponseEntity<String> getData() {
      return new ResponseEntity<>("Hello world", HttpStatus.OK);
    } 
 }
```

With this annotation added, unless I have

```
personcontroller.enabled=true
```

in my `application.properties` file, the controller won't start at all.

P.S: You might want to consider `@ConditionalOnProperty` as it's considered to be slightly faster.

Hope it helps you in some way.

Comment: this is the same as option 2, but with controller it simpler, because you dont have to replace it with empty implementation